# Firewall disabled on OSX Mountain Lion, but incoming connections still blocked

Tags: mamp, firewall

All of a sudden all incoming connections seem to be blocked to my MacBook even though firewall is off.  I discovered this because I could no longer connect with my iPhone to my MAMP server on my laptop.

Both iPhone and laptop are on the same subnet, there are no special settings in my router, and nothing seems to appear in my system logs.  I have tried to telnet from my iphone on various, supposedly open, ports on the laptop and no connection.

I have also restarted the router with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue with macOS Catalina. It started happening some days ago. Have you found a solutions for this?